# Is there a shorthand way to match all static files extensions in an IIS web.config rule?

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a rule which matches all incoming requests against a set of file types... which are basically all the static file extensions I could think of (so far). This is how my rule looks:

```
<rule name="StaticContent" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.+)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="/\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

I can already think of other extensions which are static files and not included such as `.flv, .mov, .woff, .ttf` etc. Is there a way to 'catch-all' static file extensions in a rule like the above? I am not sure how sustainable it is to keep adding to this rule whenever a new format is used by someone .e.g a developer might suddenly create a feature that converts video into 10 different formats without telling me.

What would be a better approach?

Comment: in my opinion, there is no shortcut to implement your requirement. but if you want to do not allow the unlisted file extension then you could use request filtering module in iis. in edit feature setting uncheck the allow unlisted filename extension. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdU49.png)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal How could I add all the filename extensions from the Request Filtering screen into my IIS rule? That would pretty much cover it right?

Comment: you could not add the filename Extention from request filtering to URL rewrite. you need to manually add the extension in your rule as suggested above. The request filter module scans incoming requests and rejects requests that are unwanted based upon the rules that you set up. By default, IIS rejects requests to browse critical code segments. It also rejects requests for some filename extensions.you could refer this link for more detail about the request filtering. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/)